# I am trying to access each row , in a table with a loop in rails console . But I am ending up with a wrong o/p?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

This is my table

```
id   content     from     to     have_read    created_at     updated_at
1      xyz        xxx     qwe       0           xxxx          xxxx
2      xyz        xxx     yyy       1           xxxx          xxxx
3      xyt        xxx     xxx       0           xxxx          xxxx
```

I am interested in the attribute have_read .In the rails console i am trying to display the contents of the  row containing "have_read=1".

This is the code I used:-

```
2.2.0 :187 > Message.all do |m|
2.2.0 :188 >     if m.have_read=1
2.2.0 :189?>     puts m.content
2.2.0 :190?>     end
2.2.0 :191?>   end
```

But i got the output as the whole table :

```
    Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"
         => #<ActiveRecord::Relation
 [#<Message id: 1, content: "hey", from: "sun@g.com", to: "nev@n.com", have_read: nil, created_at: "2015-03-26 05:40:08", updated_at: "2015-03-26 05:40:08">,
     #<Message id: 2, content: "hey", from: "nev@n.com", to: "sun@g.com", have_read: 1, created_at: "2015-03-26 05:42:20", updated_at: "2015-03-26 05:42:20">,
     #<Message id: 3, content: "hey", from: "nev@n.com", to: "sun@g.com", have_read: nil, created_at: "2015-03-26 05:55:15", updated_at: "2015-03-26 05:55:15">]>
```

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: you should do `if m.have_read==1`, `==` is comparison operator and `=` is assignment operator

Comment: I have tried that earlier , but i got the same output

Comment: TRy this `Message.where(have_read: 1).each  do |m| puts m.content end`

Comment: hey , thanks this is  working  , but it is displaying the whole row . I want it only to be the content attribute .

Comment: [#<Message id: 2, content: "hey", from: "nev@n.com", to: "sun@g.com", have_read: 1, created_at: "2015-03-26 05:42:20", updated_at: "2015-03-26 05:4

Comment: you can also try `Message.all.select { |m| m.have_read == 1 }.each do |m| puts m.content end`

Comment: Or `Message.select(:content).where(have_read: 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show only selected field, you have to use `select`

```
Message.select(:content).where(have_read: 1)
```

or

```
Message.all.select{ |m| m.have_read == 1 }.each do |m| 
   puts m.content 
end
```

Comment: I used this to destroy all items from a table and related data. e.g. `Message.all.each do |msg|` newline `msg.destroy` newline `end`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
read_message_content = Message.where(have_read: 1).map{|msg| msg.content}
```

This will give you all message content which has been read

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, one of your problems is that you test

`if m.have_read=1`

which will set the value of have_read to 1, and so it will always pass the `if` test, since you're effectively testing whether setting it to 1 returns 1, which it does (as the standard setter methods return the passed value after setting the attribute).

So you should be saying

`if m.have_read == 1`

to test it, since `==` is the "does this equal" operator.  (i've added some whitespace as per conventions).

Another possible issue is that if this is a boolean field, it is stored in the database as 1 or 0 (in other databases it might be 't' or 'f' or other values), but Rails translates it into a boolean when it reads it out of the table, so it will be equal to `true` or `false`.  If this is the case you should say

`if m.have_read == true`

or, you can just say

`if m.have_read`

which is logically equivalent, but more readable.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply , but I have tried that before ,(with the space ) . But i got the same o/p .
But this works "Message.where(have_read: 1).each do |m| puts m.content end" fine

Comment: What do you get back if you just say `Message.first.have_read`, in the console?